# City and State regex pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

User should able to input city and state either by city coma state or city space state.  I am trying to solve an issue. with this regex pattern.

```
/^[A-Za-z]+(\s?)+[,\s](\s?)+[A-Za-z]{2,}$/
```

All of the following inputs should return true.  But the regex fails some of them.

> New york, NY  true
>
> New york NY  **false**
>
> Seattle WA  true
>
> Seattle, WA  true
>
> Winston Salem, NC  **false**
>
> Winston Salem NC  **false**

Comment: You would also want the city, state to be correct. In that case RegEx is not the complete solution. Regex can check if city and state are separated by a comma `,`. [This regex will match all of them.](https://regex101.com/r/jQ6dK9/1) but beyond that to recognize if the city and state match is part of programming language.

Comment: What is the `(\s?)+` part (appears twice in your regex) supposed to do? Matches one or more optional spaces?

Answer (score 7):

You need these ingredients:

```
Word = [A-Za-z]+
Space = [ ]
CityName = Word (?:Space Word)*
StateAbbrev = [A-Za-z]{2}
Everything = (CityName) ,? Space (StateAbbrev)
```

Taking these together, your regular expression is:

```
/([A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Za-z]+)*),? ([A-Za-z]{2})/
```

Whenever this pattern matches, you can extract the city name and the state as capturing groups 1 and 2.